# Xamarin public variables in ContentPage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

why are the variables I have created null in my ContentPage

ReceiptPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace LiquidCalc


public partial class ReceiptPage : ContentPage
{

    public string OutAromaProp { get; set; }
    public string OutShotProp { get; set; }
    public string OutBasisProp { get; set; }

    public ReceiptPage()
    {


        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;

        OutAroma.Text = "Hallo:"+ OutAromaProp;


    }

}
```

On the MainPage

```
 var page = new ReceiptPage
        {
            OutAromaProp ="Hallo", //"Aroma: " + AromaOut.ToString() + " ml",
            OutShotProp = "Nikotien Shot " + NikoteinMG.Text + "mg: " + Math.Round(NikoteinShot).ToString() + " ml",
            OutBasisProp = "Basis: " + Math.Round(Basis).ToString() + "ml",

        };
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page,true);
```

The label only get the value "Hallo:" the the variable OutAromaProp is not assigned .
why?

Answer (score 0):

ok i have it, it wont work of async reasons.
this one solves my issue

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        OutAroma.Text = OutAromaProp;
        OutShot.Text = OutShotProp;
        OutBasis.Text = OutBasisProp;
    }
```

Comment: You can mark your answer so that more people can see it.